# Age of Empires Online Skirmish Strategy

Tags: age-of-empires-online

So i almost feel embarrased to say that i got my butt handed to me by a computer on standard. From my previous experiences with Age of Empires i would've thought I stood a better chance, yet I found myself constantly dominated in every aspect of the game. The computer had control of almost every resource and any counter i threw at him was met with a smaller force that seemed to wreck my army. I feel like maybe my way of gathering resources was inefficient or the way maybe im building wrong.

I usually start out by putting my workers half and half with food and wood, then continue to spend the rest of my food on workers till i have a decent amount. It took me a while to get to Age 2 and even longer to get to Age 3 and I gave up after that. I had one barracks towards the end i built a second, an archery range, and some other building that builds healers. also I'm playing as the Celtics, and im level 6.

Comment: What's the AI's equipment like?

Comment: they had normal full greens i guess

Comment: @JamesJiao i got to level 10 and im still finding it extremely difficult to stay alive against standard opponents idk why my armys get demolished by them they always seem stronger in the end.

Comment: Do you send Age 3/4 units at you? If yes, then you will need to level up a bit more to have access to similar units to have a chance against them.

Comment: @JamesJiao i use a combination of all the ages since they all have their strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: of course. I forgot that you have access to every unit when you play Skirmish. Maybe level a bit more and get better gear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just started playing as well and was a huge fan of AOE 2 and right now have a level 18 Greek city. Some buddies and I have been playing 4v4 skrimishes vs AI and get wrecked. We can only win if we somehow hold out long enough to resource starve the AI.

Basically what I do in order to mount a defense is build 12 villagers early game. I have 6 on food, 5 on wood, and one on gold. I can normally advance to age two by the time I have my 12th villager built. I normally have all six harvesting food before I have them harvest other resources.

Once in the second age I build 8 more villagers, sending more to wood, gold, and stone. With the stone I build walls around my city. I also build 2 barracks and 2 archery ranges. I normally build between 20-30 troops consisting of some of everything. that force will be used to hold off early attacks and possibly counter attack. From there, good luck